# How do I zip fields of a dictionary to iterate through their contents concurrently

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists:
eg

```
>>> test_dict = {"numbers":[1,2,3],"letters":['a','b','c']}
```

I want to zip up each field so that I can loop through all of the fields concurrently.
I can do this manually like this

```
>>> for number,letter in zip(test_dict["numbers"],test_dict["letters"]):
>>>    print(f"number {number}, letter {letter}")

number 1, letter a
number 2, letter b
number 3, letter c
```

Is there any way to do this better without specifying the name of the fields in the zip() command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `zip(*test_dict.values())`.

Comment: It's not clear though whether `numbers` or `letters` will go first.

Comment: @md2perpe dicts are insertion ordered since 3.7, so it's clear in that sense. If you need a different order, there's no way around specyfing that order which means putting the keys in the code again.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a double for loop:

```
test_dict = {"numbers":[1,2,3],"letters":['a','b','c'],"big letters":["A","B","C"]}
all_rows = {}
for names, items in test_dict.items():
    for idx, values in enumerate(items):
        all_rows[idx] = all_rows.get(idx,[]) + [f"{names}: {values}"]

for row in all_rows.values():
    print(*row,sep=", ")
```

results:

```
numbers: 1, letters: a, big letters: A
numbers: 2, letters: b, big letters: B
numbers: 3, letters: c, big letters: C
```

The benefit of this is that you can put values of different length together

```
test_dict = {"numbers":    [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
             "letters":    ['a','b','c'],
             "big letters":["A","B","C","D"]}
```

results:

```
numbers: 1, letters: a, big letters: A
numbers: 2, letters: b, big letters: B
numbers: 3, letters: c, big letters: C
numbers: 4, big letters: D
numbers: 5
```

Comment: could just use `itertools.zip_longest(*test_dict.values())` if you want to account for lists of different lengths